# Need to change the color of a JButton with a different shape

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, shapes

I'm making a game for class and for this game I have an array of JButtons that need to be able to change colors based on certain factors.  I had this all worked out and was changing the color with setBackground(Color) but now I am trying to change the shapes of Buttons and still be able to change the colors.
My current code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class CircleButton extends JButton {

  Graphics g = this.getGraphics();

  public CircleButton(){
    super();
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   g.setColor(Color.pink);
   g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, getSize().height-1);
   super.paintComponent(g);
}

  public void changeColor(Color c) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, getSize().height-1);
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }                        
}
```

When I change my other code to use this instead of JButton, it works and I start with an 8x8 grid of pink circles which is what I want.  But now I am unable to change colors.  I've tried adding the changeColor method as I showed above but I get a nullPointerException when it hits line 20 (g.setColor(Color.blue)).
I think the problem is with how I'm using Graphics but I can't pinpoint the specific solution.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: noooo .... you never-ever use component.getGraphics in Swing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only method supposed to be called to paint your custom component is paintComponent().

Inside that methods you are always setting pink color, and this one problem.

The other issue is that you are trying to paint your component inside the changeColor method. This is wrong. Let that function only change a variable that indicates the color.

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class CircleButton extends JButton {

 // Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
 Color col = Color.pink;
  public CircleButton(){
   //commented as unuseful.. super call is implicit if constructor has no arguments
   // super();
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   g.setColor(this.color);
   g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, getSize().height-1);
   super.paintComponent(g);
}

  public void changeColor(Color c) {
      this.color = Color.blue; //only change the color. Let paintComponent paint
      this.repaint();
  }                        
}
```

Comment: But then how do I get it to actually change the color.  It changes the color variable.  "this.color" returns an error that it can't find variable color, so I tried supplementing that with col, but all that does is change the variable, but that variable is not used until I call paintComponent.  I don't know how to call paintComponent though because I'm not sure what to use in the parameters.
EDIT:  Nevermind, fixed it.  Color worked, I just forgot to change it in paintComponent to (this.color).
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Woops, thought it was done, but I was wrong.  It pretty much works but it only updates the color when I mouse over the circle.  Does anyone know of a way to update it as soon as I change the color.
@Heisenbug

Comment: And yet again was able to fix it.  Just had to add "repaint();" to my changeColor method.
Pretty sure I am all done with this part of my code now.
Again, thank you very much.

Comment: you have to call at least repaint() after setting the color: the underlying button is unaware of that new property.

Comment: @kleopatra: yes..thanks.. I forgot the repaint  method call. Just fixed.